# How to access request/response cookies with node-fetch like chrome devtools?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, google-chrome-devtools, node-fetch

I am trying to understand why the chrome (and firefox) devtools network tab can see request/response cookies in an initial GET of a website, but node-fetch cannot.

For example, take stackoverflow.com. When I copy the initial GET with Google Chrome as a node fetch,
[image]

and try to print the request cookies, I don't get any. This is strange because per the image above, request cookies are provided by stack overflow in response to this GET.

```js
let fetch = require('node-fetch')

fetch("https://stackoverflow.com/", {
  "headers": {
    "accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;..."
    "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
    "cache-control": "no-cache",
    "pragma": "no-cache",
    "sec-ch-ua": "\" Not;A Brand\";v=\"99\", \"Google Chrome\";v=\"91\", \"Chromium\";v=\"91\"",
    "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
    "sec-fetch-dest": "document",
    "sec-fetch-mode": "navigate",
    "sec-fetch-site": "none",
    "sec-fetch-user": "?1",
    "upgrade-insecure-requests": "1",
    "cookie": "OptanonAlertBoxClosed=2021-04-07T22:42:43.384Z;..."
  },
  "referrerPolicy": "strict-origin-when-cross-origin",
  "body": null,
  "method": "GET",
  "mode": "cors"
}).then(async (resp)=> {
    console.log(resp.headers.get('set-cookie'))
});
```

(the console logs `null`). I've deleted most of the cookies in this request for brevity, but you can see the `OptanonAlertBoxClosed` in the copied fetch and in the request cookies in the image above.

### Question

Why does Chrome devtools log request cookies for a GET to stackoverflow.com, but node-fetch does not?

Comment: Where do the request cookies come from?

Comment: My understanding is that these are provided in response to my initial GET of stackoverflow.com. I did not generate the ones you see in the devtools console.

Comment: Probably the ones you see there are the ones previously stored in your browser. What I meant is that when you fetch something in node you get to choose what cookies to send!

Comment: I need to do some more investigation, but this is likely the source of my confusion - thank you!